# Why are lists created by a function not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python and don't understand much. I created a function that takes a number and puts all the integers which lead up to that number, including that number, into a list. Or so I thought, turns out I cant actually use the created list as a list. Any ideas on how I can make it useable?

---

```
def break_up(x):
"""breaks up the the integers adding up to a number x, starting at 1. Works for any positive number or 0"""
y = 1
b = 1
a = []
while y <= x:
    n = x - x + b
    b = b + 1
    y = y + 1
    a.append(n)
print(a)
```

---

Comment: Indentation is very important in python, and yours is not correct.

Comment: Instead of print, use return statement to return value from function. E.g: “return a”.

Comment: Even after you fix the indentation, your function does not _return_ anything.

Comment: What makes you think you have a list that isn't iterable? What did you do, and what was the error or unexpected result? If the error tells you something like `NoneType is not iterable`, t hen you don't have a list that isn't iterable, you have `None`.

Comment: I did the return thing and it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't realize the indentation was off on here. That was a translation issue, it's proper on my python interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

As people have commented, your indentation is incorrect, but in addition you are not actually calling the function.

The function needs to *return* an object.  An object created in a function stays there and is not visible outside (unless it is `global`) - this is called *encapsulation* and is an important programming technique which enables functions to be used anywhere.

Note that even the *multi-line comment* has to be indented (and I have made it multi-line)

Here is my version of your program:

```
def break_up(x):
    """
    breaks up the the integers adding up to a number x, starting at 1.
    Works for any positive number or 0
    """
    y = 1
    b = 1
    a = []
    while y <= x:
        n = x - x + b
        b = b + 1
        y = y + 1
        a.append(n)

    return a    # <<<< added

# At this point, the name 'a' is not visible

thing = break_up(5)

print(thing)

# or

print(break_up(5))
```

Just for fun, try this:

```
$ python3 -i gash.py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> help(break_up)
```

Comment: What you call a _multiline comment_ is not a comment but a documentation string. Python does not allow multiline comments. A comment is ignored by an interpreter. A string is not ignored. A string object is created, that can be optimized out if not assigned to any variable. By convention, the first unassigned string (single or multi-line, does not matter) is treated as a documentation string.

Comment: @DyZ: you are correct of course, but I was trying to keep it simple for the OP.  The string is being used as a multi-line comment.  The doc-string aspect was hinted at by my suggestion for using `help()`.  I didn't wish to diverge too much from the issue at hand, clearly there is a lot more to learn and there is always a danger of saying too much.